# Why is Perl 'while loop' only doing one write to MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, perl

While loop only doing one insert to table when it should be doing over 500.
I have done numerous displays to prove there are over 500 entries in @book_ids.
But only the first entry is inserted into the table.

**Relevant script code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Script to List Books Database.
# 
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Autoformat;
require 'appl.lib';
# verify access coming from proper source
my ($source) = &verify_visitor();

###### Establish connection to BookDB package
use BookDB;
my ($bookdb) = new BookDB();
my ($success);
######

#####################################################################
###### connect to the database
my ($dsn) = "DBI:mysql:webstone:localhost"; # data source name
my ($user) = "xxxxxxxxx";                    # db user name
my ($password) = "xxxxxxxx";                  # db password
my ($DBI) = "";
my (%attr) =                                # error handling attributes
(
       PrintError => 0,
       RaiseError => 0
);
my ($SQL, $str);                            # various handles
my ($db_user, $db_pw);                      # db returned user_id and pass_word
my ($login);                                # login verification switch
my ($dbh) = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, \%attr)
       || &bail_out ("Cannot connect to the database");
if(param())
{
   #do this for security reasons. It prevents bookmarking URL's with
   #passwords and the like encoded in them, and prevents some security hazards.
  die "Not a POST request!\n" unless ((request_method() eq "POST") || ($source eq "books"));
}
#####################################################################


my ($book_count, $c_count, $w_count, $s_count, @book_ids, $book_ids, @book, $book, @all_book_data, $all_book_data, $rec, $pass_book_id);
my (@rawdata, $rawdata, @un_x, $un_x, @sorted, $sorted);

### hold Master Book table data in temp table
my ($m_id, $m_book_id, $m_isbn, $m_copyright_year, $m_status, $m_title, $m_alt_title, $m_notes);
my ($m_author_id, $m_author1_name, $m_author2_name, $m_author_book_id);
my ($m_series_id, $m_series_name, $m_series_num, $m_series_book_id);
my ($m_order_id, $m_order_date, $m_due_date, $m_order_book_id);
### hold Book table data when read
my ($h_book_id, $h_isbn, $h_copyright_year, $h_status, $h_title, $h_alt_title, $h_notes);
### hold Author table data when read
my ($h_author_id, $h_last_name, $h_first_name, $h_middle_name, $h_author_book_id);
my ($h_alt_author_id, $h_alt_last_name, $h_alt_first_name, $h_alt_middle_name, $h_alt_author_book_id);
### hold Series table data when read
my ($h_series_id, $h_series_name, $h_series_num, $h_series_book_id);
### hold Order table when read
my ($h_order_id, $h_order_date, $h_due_date, $h_order_book_id);

my ($msg, $content, $page);
my $html_header = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n\n";
my ($disp_date, $date_store) = &get_today_date();

my ($sent_user) = param("username");
my ($sent_passwd) = param("passwd");
my ($action) = param("function");
my ($direct) = param("direction");
my ($choice) = param("menu_choice");

my ($p_username) = "p_username";
my ($pass_username) = param("p_username");



### Mainline
if ($action eq "list")
{
        ($success, $c_count) = $bookdb->create_temp_tbl($dbh);
        ($success, $book_count, @book_ids) = $bookdb->get_book_ids($dbh);
        my ($c);
        foreach $pass_book_id (@book_ids)
    {
                ($success, $h_book_id, $h_isbn, $h_copyright_year, $h_status, $h_title, $h_alt_title, $h_notes) = $bookdb->get_book_data($dbh, $pass_book_id);
                $m_id = $c;
                $m_book_id = $h_book_id;
                $m_isbn = $h_isbn;
                $m_copyright_year = $h_copyright_year;
                $m_status = $h_status;
                $m_title = $h_title;
                $m_alt_title = $h_alt_title;
                $m_notes = $h_notes;
                ($success, $h_author_id, $h_last_name, $h_first_name, $h_middle_name, $h_author_book_id) = $bookdb->get_author1_data($dbh, $pass_book_id);
                $m_author_id = $h_author_id;
                $m_author_book_id = $h_author_book_id;
                $m_author1_name = $h_last_name . ", " . $h_first_name . " " . $h_middle_name;
                ($success, $h_alt_author_id, $h_alt_last_name, $h_alt_first_name, $h_alt_middle_name, $h_alt_author_book_id) = $bookdb->get_author2_data($dbh, $pass_book_id, $h_author_id);
                if ($h_alt_author_id)
                {
                        $m_author2_name = $h_alt_last_name . ", " . $h_alt_first_name . " " . $h_alt_middle_name;
                }
                else
                {
                        $m_author2_name = "";
                }
                ($success, $h_series_id, $h_series_name, $h_series_num, $h_series_book_id) = $bookdb->get_series_data($dbh, $pass_book_id);
                if ($h_series_id)
                {
                        $m_series_id = $h_series_id;
                        $m_series_book_id = $h_series_book_id;
                        $m_series_name = $h_series_name;
                        $m_series_num = $h_series_num;
                }
                else
                {
                        $m_series_id = "";
                        $m_series_book_id = "";
                        $m_series_name = "";
                        $m_series_num = "";
                }
                ($success, $h_order_id, $h_order_date, $h_due_date, $h_order_book_id) = $bookdb->get_order_data($dbh, $pass_book_id);
                if ($h_order_id)
                {
                        $m_order_id = $h_order_id;
                        $m_order_book_id = $h_order_book_id;
                        $m_order_date = $h_order_date;
                        $m_due_date = $h_due_date;
                }
                else
                {
                        $m_order_id = "";
                        $m_order_book_id = "";
                        $m_order_date = "";
                        $m_due_date = "";
                }
                ($success, $w_count) = $bookdb->write_temp_tbl($dbh, $m_id, $m_book_id,
                        $m_isbn, $m_copyright_year, $m_status, $m_title, $m_alt_title, $m_notes,
                        $m_author_id, $m_author1_name, $m_author2_name, $m_author_book_id,
                        $m_series_id, $m_series_name, $m_series_num, $m_series_book_id,
                        $m_order_id, $m_order_date, $m_due_date, $m_order_book_id);
        }
        my ($g);
        for ($g = 0; $g < $book_count; $g++)
    {
                $pass_book_id = $book_ids[$g];
                ($success, $s_count, $m_id, $m_book_id, $m_isbn, $m_copyright_year, $m_status, $m_title, $m_alt_title, $m_notes,
                        $m_author_id, $m_author1_name, $m_author2_name, $m_author_book_id,
                        $m_series_id, $m_series_name, $m_series_num, $m_series_book_id,
                        $m_order_id, $m_order_date, $m_due_date, $m_order_book_id)
                        = $bookdb->get_temp_data($dbh, $pass_book_id);
    }
##################### D E B U G ##############################################
print header,
    start_html,
    p("Track book data after final get<br>"),
    p("book_ids: @book_ids<br>"),
    p("pass_book_id: $pass_book_id - h_author_id: $h_author_id - h_last_name: $h_last_name<br>"),
    p("m_id: $m_id - m_book_id: $m_book_id - m_isbn: $m_isbn - m_title: $m_title - m_author1_name: $m_author1_name - m_series_name: $m_series_name - m_series_num: $m_series_num - m_order_date: $m_order_date<br>"),
    p("book_count: $book_count - c: $c - g: $g - c_count: $c_count - w_count: $w_count - s_count: $s_count<br>"),
    p("-----------------------------------<br>"),
    end_html;
exit;
##################### D E B U G ################################################################### D E B U G

    exit;
}
&bail_out ("Invalid choice. - list_all.pl - Choice: $action");
&all_done();
exit;

sub get_html()
{
    $page = `cat /home/rmelia/public_html/books/cgi_list.shtml`;
} # end sub get_html

sub put_html()
{
    $page =~ s/<!--books: cgi\s*-->/$content/g;
    print $html_header, $page;
} # end sub put_html
```

**Relevant Module code:**

```
sub write_temp_tbl()
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $dbh = shift;
    my $w_count = 0;
    my $m_id = shift;
    my $m_book_id = shift;
    my $m_isbn = shift;
    my $m_copyright_year = shift;
    my $m_status = shift;
    my $m_title = shift;
    my $m_alt_title = shift;
    my $m_notes = shift;
    my $m_author_id = shift;
    my $m_author1_name = shift;
    my $m_author2_name = shift;
    my $m_author_book_id = shift;
    my $m_series_id = shift;
    my $m_series_name = shift;
    my $m_series_num = shift;
    my $m_series_book_id = shift;
    my $m_order_id = shift;
    my $m_order_date = shift;
    my $m_due_date = shift;
    my $m_order_book_id = shift;

    my $success = (1==2);

    $sth = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO webstone.temp
                (m_id, m_book_id, m_isbn, m_copyright_year, m_status,
                m_title, m_alt_title, m_notes,
                m_author_id, m_author1_name, m_author2_name, m_author_book_id,
                m_series_id, m_series_name, m_series_num, m_series_book_id,
                m_order_id, m_order_date, m_due_date, m_order_book_id)
                VALUES
                ('1', '$m_book_id', '$m_isbn', '$m_copyright_year', '$m_status',
                '$m_title', '$m_alt_title', '$m_notes',
                '$m_author_id', '$m_author1_name', '$m_author2_name', '$m_author_book_id',
                '$m_series_id', '$m_series_name', '$m_series_num', '$m_series_book_id',
                '$m_order_id', '$m_order_date', '$m_due_date', '$m_order_book_id')
                ");
    $sth->execute();
    if ( !$sth )
        {
        die "Couldn't execute insert statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
    }
    elsif ($sth->rows == 0)
        {
        die "INSERT INTO temp Failed - SQL error: " . $dbh->errstr . "<br>\n";
    }
    else
        {
        #die "SQL insert successful, rows = " . $sth->rows() . "<br>\n";
        $success = (1==1);
    }

        $w_count++;
    $sth->finish;
        return ($success, $w_count);
} # end sub write_temp_tbl
```

I have also tried 'for loops' and 'foreach loops' in place of the 'while loop'.
None of my research has even come close to an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you try to put the $sth->execute() after the loop?

Comment: `@book_ids` and `$book_ids` are different. i guess you may want for-each instead.

Comment: You should try and create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. And you should never write code without `use warnings; use strict;`, especially when using so many variables with similar names.

Comment: A comment, because it's not answering your question, but trying to save you a lot of trouble:  **use placeholders!**  The documention for DBI.pm shows how to use placeholders and bind values.

Comment: @TLP
**use warnings;** and **use strict;** were both in effect.
(I always use both.)

To: jcho360
Would that cause all 500+ inserts to be executed at once?

Comment: @user1460597 I assumed you did not use them because I did not see you take advantage of lexically scoped variables anywhere, except in the subroutine. It is a very helpful tool to use.

Comment: @user1460597: The `execute` after the loop would not do that. It would prepare each statement and forget about it. It might (depending on the scope of `$sth`) execute the prepared statement that was created in the last iteration of the loop. In short: don't do it.

Comment: Can you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11086075/edit) your question to show a little more detail about the data, and also update to the code you now have? It's really hard to help you like this.

Comment: @simbabque: I updated the script code to show the entire code as it last ran.

Comment: What do the `m_*` and `h_*` variables do? What's the difference between `m` and `h`? Why are some of them defined outside the loop?

Comment: Another thought: What is `$c` doing? You declare it with a value of `undef`. Then you assign it to `$m_id`, which becomes `undef`, too. The next time `$m_id` shows up is when you cann `write_temp_tbl()`. But in your insert statement, you always put a `1` into the `m_id` field. You never change the value of either `$c` or `$m_id` after that. - Have you put some debug `print` statements in the `write_temp_tbl()` sub to see if it is executed several times at all? Try `Data::Dumper::Dumper()`ing your `@book_ids` right before the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @simbabque: h_* vars hold data pulled off from 4 different tables. m_* vars (loaded from the h_* vars) go into the combined table that is created during the foreach loop. All are defined at initialization, before processing.

Comment: $c was being used for a display count when debugging at one point. (Several of those around!) $m_id is the auto-increment index for the combined table being created. Shouldn't matter what is being put in there, MySQL should take care of it. I was only playing with it during debugging to see if it made a difference. Didn't! Yes, write_temp_tbl() only gets executed once. Prior to that, display shows 526 items in @books_ids.

Comment: This has been so baffling and time consuming, I just know the solution will be simple, and embarrassing. PS. How do you get the nice formatting for vars like $c and m_id? (This is my first question - took me an hour to find out how to format code! heh, heh!) BTW, thx for your time!

Comment: Put the debug `print` in the `write_temp_tbl`. Try `Dumper`ing all the params right after you `shift` them. Best use `print Dumper [$var1, $var2..]` format. If in CGI, wrap it in `<xmp></xmp>`. Figure out how often it is called and what data it gets. That will tell you if the problem is in the code or the data or the DB.

Comment: Click the [help] link next to the comment box. Let's move this to a chat, but not now. Are you around in two hours?

Comment: @simbabque: Available for chat? Tried sending you my e-mail in a comment. No go!

Comment: I am, but I'm afraid you cannot use the chat yet because your rep is below 20.

Comment: I created a chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12944/why-is-perl-while-loop-only-doing-one-write-to-mysql-table

Comment: Please don't post your email address. I suggest you try to [gain some reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) so you can use the chat. I'm not going to contact you through email as I'm not your personal teacher. If you want help you have will have to earn it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to suddenly invent a variable called `$book_ids` which hasn't been given a value. I suspect you actually wanted something like:

```
foreach my $pass_book_id (@book_ids) {
  ...
}
```

This is one of those places where `use strict` and `use warnings` would have helped you track down the problem.

Comment: **foreach my $pass_book_id (@book_ids)**
Still just one record inserted into table!

Comment: Then it looks like there's only one element in @book_ids. This is when you reach for the debugger or (at the very least) start putting `print` statements into your program to trace its execution.

Comment: Dave: Did print statements every step of the way. 526 items in @book_ids. Everything looks good, only problem is the 'foreach loop' only appears to execute once causing one record to be inserted. I know, it's baffling, and I have been trying everything I can to make it work for quite a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave already said: First of all, allways `use strict` and `use warnings`. It usually tells you the simple things one tends to forget.

Once you've added that I suggest you take a look at the [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#prepare) documentation.

To get you started, here's a simple script that does something similar to what you are trying to achieve (I guess).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('datasource goes here', 'username', 'password');

# Here are our books, there's one hashref for each book
my @books = (
  {
    'author' => 'J. K. Rowling',
    'title' => 'Harry Potter and the Perl Book',
    'ISBN' => '123456789',
  },
  {
    'author' => 'J. K. Rowling',
    'title' => 'Harry Potter and another Perl Book',
    'ISBN' => '123456787',
  },
);

# sth is short for STatement Handle
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO book ( author, title, isbn ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )');
foreach my $book (@books) {
  $sth->execute(
    $book->{'author'},
    $book->{'title'},
    $book->{'ISBN'},
  );
}
$sth->finish;
```

In short: Prepare your statement and use [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#Placeholders). They take care of escaping, protect you from SQL injection and speed up the queries. If you prepare your statement only once and you can reuse it. The `?` are the placeholders.

Comment: & DavidO
Thanks for the placeholders tip.
Once I get the script working correctly, I will add the placeholders.

Comment: Thanks for the placeholders tip. Once I get the script working correctly, I will add the placeholders.